# How to check if a key has no value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key, feed

I have two feeds and i want with the content of them to populate a table view, but when i want to display the images the key are diffrents so in cellForRowAtIndexPath i have:

```
 if ([[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"] ==nil) {
        [cell.imag setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"_text"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Alb.png"]];
    }

    else
        [cell.imag setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Alb.png"]];
```

but it's not working.

Comment: use this code  if ([dictionary objectForKey:key]) {
    // contains object}

Comment: put break points to print the value in the console [stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"] What value it prints....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
if ([dictionary objectForKey:key]) {
// contains object
}
else
{
//no object
}
```